# Poincaré Index Method (fingerprint singular points)

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, geometry, fingerprint

I'm working on a  biometric project and i need to determine the singular points of a fingerprint. For this i use the Poincaré Index method described in *Handbook of Fingerprint Recognition*, D. Maltoni, D. Maio, K. Jain, S. Prabhakar and i am unable to understand the highlighted statement in the image below.

[image]

What i did was to determine the orientation map of my fingerprint image and then i simply added the differences between those values around a block. (divided the image in blocks of 13x13).But i am unable to determine the right points. 
 Can someone please explain the highlighted statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have converted the image and taken cells and created an orientation line for the ridge in that cell, these orientation lines aren't directional a->b, they are an angle, e.g. 43 degrees but note that direction is the same as 223 degrees or -137 degrees. So what the sentence is saying is that as you move from cell to cell, you take the orientation line of the next cell and look at how different its direction is from the current one, and use the direction for it which is the least different from the current cell as the direction of this next cell. The difference in orientation between two cells will then always be in the range -179.9999999~ to +180.0 degrees.

The Poincare method then says to sum the difference in direction of these directions around a closed loop - if necessary applying the same rule from the ultimate cell back to the origin cell when comparing the last cell to it, and this sum indicates the type of node at the centre of the closed loop. Your previous question [Fingerprint singular point detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525728/fingerprint-singular-point-detection) showed exactly this. Presumably you apply this centred around every cell of the fingerprint image, discard the zeros and what is left are the significant nodes.

Have you tried visualising your cell directions over the image to make sure you have got sensible direction for each cell?

Comment: I got it now, i was comparing orientations, not direction..stupid mistake.